# Create unique ID with constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I want to create objects with a name and a unique ID number that increments with the creation of each user.

```
class user {

    static int uid = 0;
    String name;

    public user (String name){
       User.uid = uid++;
       this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When creating user objects in a main method and printing out their ID they all return 0. I think there is a simply fix to this but can't seem to find it elsewhere online.

Comment: You can not do that. A deserialization can create a user without calling the constructor. There is no guarantee that the id is unique.

Comment: @PeterRader User is not serializable, so it can't be serialized anyway. The OP is a newbie learning about fields. Serialization, thread safety, clustering are not problems he/she should care about for now.

Comment: @JBNizet You are telling me a non-final class can not be serialized?

Comment: No. I've never mentioned final anywhere. I'm telling you that a class that doesn't implement java.io.Serializable can't be serialized, and that serialization is irrelevant anyway, since the OP is just practicing with basic features of the language, and not trying to design a distributed production application.

Comment: The code is a non-final class and you are telling it can not be serialized. A instance of a class extending `user` is also an instance of `user`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

1. A User doesn't have any ID. All you have is a static ID, thus shared by all users
2. You're incrementing the static ID, and then assigning its previous value to the ID right after.
3. You're not respecting the Java naming conventions.

The code should be

```
class User {

    private static int uid = 0;

    private String name;
    private int id;

    public User(String name) {
       uid++;
       this.id = uid;
       this.name = name;
    }

    // getters
}
```

or, if you want the IDs to start at 0:

```
class User {

    private static int uid = 0;

    private String name;
    private int id;

    public User(String name) {
       this.id = uid++;
       this.name = name;
    }

    // getters
}
```